Is there a way to "expand" an enum in C++ for "type-switching"?
For a project I need an observer class (owned by a Subject that then notifies all of its observers) that handles other behaviours.
These observers work by calling their onNotify( Event* ) method that then executes some behaviour based on the type of observer.
The way the method works is as follows:
void SpecificObserver::onNotify( const Event* nevent )
{
    switch (nevent->GetId())
    {
    case EventId::Eventtype1:
        {
            const Eventtype1* type1 = dynamic_cast<const Eventtype1*>(nevent);
                        //some behaviour...
        }
        break;
    case EventId::Eventtype2:
        {
            const Eventtype2* type2 = dynamic_cast<const Eventtype2*>(nevent);
            //some other behaviour...
        }
        break;
    }
}

So the method gets a pointer to a basic Event that only has as a GetId() method and no info, and based on that ID we know what type of event that is and we can cast to that, unlocking the other information it owns.
As it's coded now it's something like this:
enum class EventId{ Event, Eventtype1, Eventtype2 };

class Event
{
public:
    virtual EventId GetId() const { return EventId::Event; }
};

As you noticed I have to define EVERY TYPE OF EVENT before the event itself, so if I want to add a new type of event I would have to edit the event code.
My question is:
Is there a way to only have an
enum class EventId{ };
that we can then add elements to where they are needed (I.E., where we actually define Event1, Event2...)?
something like
enum class EventId { //add element Eventtype1 };

class Event1 : public Event
{
public:
    Event1( Info* i )
        :
        i(i)
    {}
    EventId GetId() const override
    { return EventId::Eventtype1; }
public:
    Info* i;
};

This way not every type of event or type of observer that uses said event would even need to know about all the other types of event that there are, as they are useless to them, and it would actually be possible to "extend" the types of events that we have without editing the Event class itself.

You could write if (auto* type1 = dynamic_cast<const Eventtype1*>(nevent)) { /* handle event type 1 */ } and drop GetId altogether.

@IgorTandetnik that would be a nice option, but wouldn't I still need to have at least one virtual function to be able to dynamic_cast? That would mean that I have a useless function (which is never called) that I still have to overload in every new subclass, and when type switching I'd have to try multiple times which is not super optimal, as it'd be quite slow. I wouldn't need to have the id anymore, but I'd rather have an enum that I have to go expand than have some much slower chain of if-elses that try every possible cast.

Usually, a virtual destructor is an obvious choice. It's certainly called.

After some time thinking about what I needed to do, I opted to use an ID based on a unique integer instead of an enum. I found something on the internet and modified it to suit my needs better:
#define ADD_UNIQUE_ID \
private: \
    static void getUniqueIdPrivate() { std::string val(__FILE__); volatile int val2 = __LINE__; } \
public: \
    virtual const size_t getUniqueId() const { return reinterpret_cast<size_t>(getUniqueIdPrivate); } \
    static size_t getClassUniqueId() { return reinterpret_cast<size_t>(getUniqueIdPrivate); }

What this does is it creates a static function for the class, and then uses the memory address to that function as an ID. It gives two different ways to access said function, one virtual as to be able to access it through a base-class pointer, and one static as to be able to access it without needing to create an instance.
It's not as easy as what I was looking for, but it's a nice hack, especially if we define it as a macro that we can then easily add to our classes.
